# Sed to Replace & and slashes

Tags: sed

I have a data in below format.

```
  new_name='abc &eft /  def \ mno' 

 1.json
  {
    "text": {
              "attribute": "old_name",
              "data": "xyz"
             }
  }
```

I am trying to replace the value old_name by new_name.

My trail :--

```
 sed  "s/old_name/${new_name/&/\&}; s/old_name/${new_name////\/}/g" 1.json
```

I get below error :--

```
 sed: -e expression #1, char 67: unknown option to `s'
```

Any guidance would be of great help.

Comment: Would suggest to use tools like `jq` and `dasel` for processing json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the need to escape the slash by using a different delimiter for the substitution, but you still need to do one of the other replacements outside the sed command:

```sh
new_name='abc &eft /  def \ mno'
quoted=${new_name/\\/\\\\\\\\}
sed "s=old_name=${quoted//&/\\&}=g" 1.json
```

But `jq` is far better tool to handle json:

```sh
new_name='abc &eft /  def \ mno'
jq --arg n "$new_name" \
    '.text.attribute |= (if . == "old_name" then $n else . end)' 1.json
```